# Delphi - Passing query results between units?

Tags: delphi

In one unit I'm running a query which will return one users details from the database. Right now I'm thinking of creating a user object and assigning the results of the query to the different properties, the setting that as a global variable. I wanted to know if there was a way to pass the data between the units without having to use the global variables.

Comment: how about using public properti ?

Comment: Put the query in a datamodule, and then add the datamodule to the units that need access to the query results. The query itself would be the shared container.

Comment: Learn object oriented programming, learn to create classes, and have those classes interact.  One pattern for this interaction is MVVM, another is called MVC, and you could even invent and use your own interaction patterns.  Some of those classes will inherit from TForm and probably be called Views, and some will be Data Access Layer objects which inherit from TDataModule and contain queries. In between you might want Controllers or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding global variables is actually a good idea. Also, storing the query result as properties of a (database-independent) object makes sense, because the application might need the information also when the connection is not active.

To avoid a global variable, the easiest way would be to make the object a field of a main form (or datamodule), and use Getter methods to make it (and its fields) read-only. I would also implement the procedure of loading the dataset values into the object properties as a spearate class.